# Do we say "I do lat pull-downs" when I pull a cable horizontally a lat machine?

Tags: phrase-usage

**Lat pull-down** is a strength training exercise designed to develop the latissimus dorsi muscle. ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pull-down_(exercise))).

This is a machine that you do lat pull-downs on:

[image]

However, there are other machines that you don't pull the cable vertically on like that. Instead, you pull the cable horizontally like this.

[image]

Do we still say "**I do lat pull-downs**" when you work out on that machine?

Someone said we can say "**I do lat pull-overs**"?

However, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pullover_(exercise)) said "**pullover**" is a different form of exercise

[image]

Do we say "**I do lat pull-acrosses**" or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

I think the exercise of pulling the cable horizontally like in the second image you provided is called a **seated row** or a **seated cable row**. So you could say:

> "I do seated rows"